# Why does "Don't you Dare" equal "Do not you dare"?

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

"Don't you dare" makes grammatical sense but why does "Do not you dare" not make grammatical sense?

Comment: Who says it doesn't?

Comment: Then why does 'do not you dare' make sense?

Comment: [Related ELU post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341897/why-do-we-say-dont-you-dare)

Comment: It does make sense - it's just that no-one would use _do not_ in an informal command like that, so it sounds unnatural.

Comment: ***Think you not*** that conventional syntax may have changed over time? ***Dare I not*** suggest that just because we don't normally explicitly identify the addressee in imperatives doesn't mean we *can't* do so. ***You! Do not dare insult me**!*